# Extract certain Columns and Rows from a json string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I get a JSON response like this from a server,

{
id : 1,
text : 'Name      City   Country  \nJohn  \n Chicago \nIllinois \nAlbert \nHouston \nTexas  '
}

if I do console.log(response.text);  the output is like this in tabular form

[image: Table Image 1]

Now I want only want the Name column along with the rows and the output should look like this

[image: Table Image 2]

Suggest me a workaround for this. Since the value is a string I'm facing a lot of trouble to extract only the required columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but something like this should work:

```
var jsonData = "{ id : 1, text : 'Name City Country \nJohn \n Chicago \nIllinois \nAlbert \nHouston \nTexas ' }";

var obj1 = jsonData.split('\n');

for(var i= 1; i<obj1.length-2; i=i+3) 
{
  console.log("Name: " +obj1[i]+", City: "+obj1[i + 1]+", Country: " +obj1[i + 2]);

}
```

Comment: can you explain me why we used i=1 instead of i=0 and obj1.length-2 instead of obj1.length ?

Answer (score 0):

Use trim and split to get the Name City and Country texts.

```js
const obj = { id : 1, text : 'Name City Country \nJohn \n Chicago \nIllinois \nAlbert \nHouston \nTexas ' }

console.log(obj.text.split("\n")[0].trim().split(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the javascript csv parser to parse the text to csv and access the particular column.

Ref: [javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)